# how to update jquery mobile popup dialog using ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, primefaces, jquery-mobile-popup, primefaces-mobile

When a jquery-mobile popup(Dialog) is opened, when clicking a command link inside the dialog, ajax request will update the dialog with the same popup markup with different header and content.

```
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(id)).replaceWith(content);
```

id is popupDialog, and content is

```
<div id="popupDialog" 
     data-role="popup" 
     data-overlay-theme="b" 
     data-theme="b" 
     data-dismissible="false">
....
</div>
```

But got error.

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.
```

It is a normal ajax update DOM element. What might be the cause? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Perhaps go a bit simpler. In your popup use spans to wrap the text you want to change, and then do $("#somespan").text("new text") ?

Comment: there is no inner wrapper around popup header and content. Need to update two elements in this way. Does Primefaces ajax support replacing children with children?